# WPF Datgrid binding text with tooltip to to different properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I want to show the body of an email in a tooltip and a shortened version in the column

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Body}"
        Header="{x:Static t:Resource.GridBody}" Width="100">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding Text, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource Self}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

I get the ellipsis on each character, I have a property that has the first three lines and I would like to bind that to the column and the body to the ToolTip

Comment: You cant see the `Text` in tooltip now ?

Comment: Just curious, why are you using two different properties for this? Text trimming should handle trimming the email, just set the height to adjust how many lines to show.

Comment: @Hrethric No it does not because it contains Newlines and the Textblock puts Ellipsis on each line

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I can see tool tip but the TextBlock has Ellipsis on each line not jut the first line. It shows all  the text with Ellipsis inpalce of Newlines

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using style I used a DataGridTemplateColumn instead of a DataGridTextColumn

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="{x:Static t:Resource.GridBody}" Width="150">
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortBody}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" ToolTip="{Binding Body}" />
       </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```